# Customise Keybord and autocorrection type for UIWebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, rich-text-editor

I am using UIWebview in my app as richtexteditor, but when i am trying to return the keyboard by hitting 'Return' key on key board,it is working as enter button and control comes to next line 
i am using this code,
- (void)viewDidLoad

```
{
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.activeElement.blur()"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

}
```

and how to Disable autocorect for the same, i want to use the code

```
<input type=\"text\" size=\"30\" autocorrect=\"off\" autocapitalization=\"off
```

and where and how should i write this code?

[image: this is the screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Code like `<input type="text" size="30" autocorrect="off" autocapitalization="on">` has to go in the actual HTML that is being shown in the UIWebview.

As for how to make the keyboard go away when the user presses return, that'll depend on how your app is set up.

If you want to actually make the WebView submit the form by HTTP, then you want to add some JavaScript to your textarea:

```
<textarea onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { this.form.submit(); return false; }"></textarea>
```

Otherwise, there's no way to listen to the return key on the keyboard, so instead you'll have to add a different button for the user to press instead. If you want to add that to the accessory view of the keyboard—well, you can't, but here's a question on making it look like your new button is part of the keyboard accessory view:

[iPhone - Adding a button to keyboard existing accessory view (keyboard from UIWebView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824325/iphone-adding-a-button-to-keyboard-existing-accessory-view-keyboard-from-uiwe)

Comment: Thanks for respnse,i add that code in my Html file and still it is not working

Comment: <textarea onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { this.form.submit(); return false; }"></textarea>
I placed this code in my local Html document,but a small textfield like thing is appearing on Webview,key board is not disappearing

Comment: Please check the Screenshot that i added in my question