# Decimal point on numeric keypad on iphone in Phonegap / Cordova

Tags: ios, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova, ios7

I am developing an iPhone application where I need to insert values with decimal point. I have tried step="any" or step="0.01" or  but it doesn't show decimal point on numeric keyboard.I am using phone gap / cordova.

My current line of code is as `<input name="abc" pattern="\d+(\.\d*)?" type="number">`

Please help!! thank you.

Comment: input type=number assuming that it is phonegap

Comment: @ShoaibChikate, check my new edits in question.

Answer (score 5):

Try using pattern to your input type="number" field

```
pattern="\d+(\.\d*)?"
```

This will bring the full keyboard but in the number/symbol pane be default. The user can still switch to alphanumeric but upon onblur event, the pattern kicks in and removes any alphanumeric characters (but not numbers).  It has to be both type="number" and pattern="\d+(.\d*)?" in order to work

But if you are developing for IOS you might find this question useful

[iPhone - Adding a button to keyboard existing accessory view (keyboard from UIWebView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824325/iphone-adding-a-button-to-keyboard-existing-accessory-view-keyboard-from-uiwe)

Comment: this is my current code '<input name="abc" pattern="\d+(\.\d*)?" type="number">'

can i use webview along with Phonegap / Cordova

Comment: Yes you can use webview.By default all html javascript apps build usind cordova or phonegap are rendered in webview